# Unable to connect to stomp (activemq) push data server in python, whereas in Java it succeeds

Tags: java, python, push-notification, activemq-classic, stomp

In Java I'm able connect to a data push service and subscribe to it. It's a `stomp` or `OpenWire` protocol I believe. The point is, this java code works well (it's a part of it):

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;

ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(API_KEY, API_KEY, "ssl://api.something.com:61616");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.setClientID(clientId);

session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.createTopic(topicName);
messageConsumer = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, subId);
JMSMessageListener listener = new JMSMessageListener();
messageConsumer.setMessageListener(listener);
connection.start();
```

However in Python I can't do this with the error being `stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException`. The code:

```
import stomp

URL = "ssl://api.something.com"
PORT = 61616

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
  def on_message(self, headers, message):
    #...
  def on_error(self, headers, message):
    #...

conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(URL, PORT)], prefer_localhost=False)
conn.set_listener("", MyListener())
conn.start() # error -> stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException
```

What am I doing wrong? As you can see, the protocol, url and port is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect STOMP clients to the OpenWire port which will of course fail since they are two different protocols.  You need to connect STOMP clients to a port that is backed by a STOMP transportConnector.

```
<transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Answer (score 2):

On my activemq.xml configuration:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Which work with this python code as send.py:

```
import stomp
import sys
import time

URL = "localhost"
PORT = 61613

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)

conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(URL, PORT)], prefer_localhost=False)
conn.set_listener("", MyListener())
conn.start()

conn.connect('q_user', 'q_password', wait=True) # change user/password as your system setup

conn.send(body='Test from Python', destination='/queue/SAMPLEQUEUE') # chage Queue name as your system setup

time.sleep(2)
conn.disconnect()
```

Then run:
$ python send.py

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to connect to ('tcp://....', 61616).
i just removed tcp:// path and it works

```
c = stomp.Connection([('v....ru', 61616)], prefer_localhost=False)
c.connect()
```